# How can I download .ods data from web to R?

Tags: r, ods

I would like to ask how I could download an .ods dataset from web (specifically this site: https://knowledge4policy.ec.europa.eu/territorial/ardeco-online_en?fbclid=IwAR1CPVLzdey8MnMZDLA-9NpvMDAJqMq1WHmm6yu8FtRAk01u9K184wCU7Wc) directly to R? I tried the following `read_ODS` code

```
a <- read_ods(path = url("https://knowledge4policy.ec.europa.eu/sites/default/files/RNPTD.ods"), sheet = 1)
```

and got the error

> "Error in file.exists(file) : invalid 'file' argument"

Did I make a mistake here or does `read_ods` load only local files?

Comment: "Does the readODS package work" Yes - have you tried it?

Comment: My apologies, had an incomplete question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work fine:

```r
url1 <- "https://knowledge4policy.ec.europa.eu/sites/default/files/RNPTD.ods"
f <- tempfile()
download.file(url1, dest=f)
x <- readODS::read_ods(f)
unlink(f)
```

That is, you can't read **directly** from an ODS file located at a URL (or at least, it didn't work for me), but downloading to a temp file and reading works.

Comment: I tried this for "https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1124025/COVID-19-transport-use-statistics.ods" but I get the error:
cannot locate file 'content.xml' in zip file 'C:\Users\[user_name]\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQ9lK6e\file391c7265'

Comment: It works for me. Possibly a problem with spaces in your path?  Otherwise can't think what it would be. If you don't mind cluttering your workspace a little, try `f <- "tmp.ods"` instead ...

Comment: Strange! Fortunately they also give a csv which I have managed to read in without any issues!