# How do I fix this error when importing an ODS file from web in R?

Tags: r

After having followed the suggested method to download ODS files ([How can I download .ods data from web to R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69452146/how-can-i-download-ods-data-from-web-to-r)), I've run into an issue that I can't seem to solve.

When running the below code:

```
library("readODS")

url <- "https://fingertips.phe.org.uk/documents/EMData.ods"
f <- tempfile()
download.file(url, dest=f)
x <- readODS::read_ods(f)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: 'C:\Users\JGxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpET6RnN/content.xml' does not exist.
In addition: Warning message:
In unzip(file, files = "content.xml", exdir = exdir) :
requested file not found in the zip file
```

Comment: Are you on Windows? This worked fine for me on my mac. Maybe try `download.file(url, dest=f, mode="wb")`. An ods file is apparently just a zip file so what do you get if you run `unzip(f, list=TRUE)`?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am indeed on WIndows.
Your first suggestion of including mode="wb" worked like a charm, many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

MrFlick has answered the question in his comment above (thank you!).
As I am a windows user, it looks like I need to amend my download.file function to allow for mode="wb".

```
library("readODS")

url <- "https://fingertips.phe.org.uk/documents/EMData.ods"
f <- tempfile()
download.file(url, dest=f, mode = "wb")
x <- read_ods(f)
```